# Jenkinsfile not passing parameter to Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

When I launch a build with parameters, I have this 'choice parameter' named "modeDebug"; the choice can be "true" or "false" (I did not choose the boolean type because I'll add more options some day). I need to use this parameter in my Java code but, for some reason, it's not retrieved.

I have this step in my Jenkinsfile in order to run the tests with parameters:

```
sh 'mvn -gs "$MAVEN_SETTINGS" -Dta.test.suite="{\\"filter\\":\\"'+newTestList+'\\",\\"param\\":{\\"env.devEnv\\":\\"${environnement}\\",\\"env.browser\\":\\"${browser}\\",\\"env.modeDebug\\":\\"${modeDebug}\\"}}"
-Denv.devEnv="${environnement}"
-Denv.browser="${browser}"
-Denv.modeDebug="${modeDebug}"
-Dlog4j.configurationFile="${log4j2ConfigurationFile}"
-Dstatus.update.events.url="${notificationURL}"
-Dsquash.ta.external.id="${externalJobId}" -Djobname="${JOB_NAME}"
-Dhostname="${HOSTNAME}" -Dsquash.ta.conf.file="taLinkConf.properties"
-Dta.tmcallback.reportbaseurl="${JENKINS_URL}job"
-Dta.tmcallback.jobexecutionid="${BUILD_NUMBER}"
-Dta.tmcallback.reportname=Squash_TA_HTML_Report
-Dta.delete.json.file=true squash-ta:"${operation}"'
```

Then, in my code, I call some of these Maven parameters...

```
protected String getScreenshotIfFail = java.lang.System.getProperty("env.modeDebug");
protected String devEnv    = java.lang.System.getProperty("env.devEnv");
protected String browser   = java.lang.System.getProperty("env.browser");
```

String devEnv and browser get populated but not ggetScreenshotIfFail!

**Notes**: In my Jenkinsfile, `echo "${modeDebug}"` outputs "true" or "false". This part is working.
In my code when the tests are run via Jenkins, `System.out.println(getScreenshotIfFail);` outputs "null".
In my IDE, I run the following command with success (getScreenshotIfFail is correctly populated):

```
-Denv.modeDebug=true -Denv.devEnv=qualif -Denv.browser=chrome -Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/log4j2.xml -Dta.test.suite=squash/**.ta squash-ta:run
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RTM - [String interpolation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation).

```
sh 'mvn ...'
   ^
  that single quote should be double quote.
```

And of course you'll have to change many other quotes in your string.